# Selenium Python Behave framework - How do I click on an element_by _id

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-behave

I am working with Behave framework in Python, which i have not used before, and I am not sure how I can click on an element_by_id. There is a cookie popup that I need to get around before I can send login keys.

This is my .features file:

```
Feature: 
Login Functionality

Scenario: I can login

When visit url "https://example.com"

When I click on the button "accept-cookie-notification"

When field with name "user_email_login" is given "@gmail.com"

When field with name "user_password" is given "password"

Then title becomes "Dashboard"
```

Here is my .py file:

## Steps

```
@when('visit url "{url}"')
def step(context, url):
    context.browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)

@when('I click on the button "{selector}"')
def step(context, selector,):
    elem = context.driver.find_element_by_id("selector")
    elem.submit()
    time.sleep(5)

@when('field with name "{selector}" is given "{value}"')
def step(context, selector, value):
    elem = context.browser.find_element_by_id(selector)
    elem.send_keys(value)
    elem.submit()
    time.sleep(5)

@then('title becomes "{title}"')
def step(context, title):
    assert context.browser.title == title
```

Also I will need to do element_by_css and xpath later on.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Provide your url or post relevant html?

Comment: I realized i had a syntax error: 
elem = context.driver.find_element_by_id("selector") . 

which should be elem = context.browser.find_element_by_id(selector)

I made the change and it ran fine, but I cannot get sleep to work may have to find a different pause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with Selenium is very simple if you are using Behave. Just install behave-webdriver package https://pypi.org/project/behave-webdriver/ It's a step library with a wide set of already defined steps with given-when-then decorators like: `I click on the element "{element}"`  and you can use both id,css and XPath as {element} parameter. You do not need to implement anything, just use predefined steps in your scenarios. Here are my code examples:

```
Scenario: A user can log in.
Given the base url is "http://my_site:3000"
And I open the site "/#/login"
And the element "#email" is visible
When I add "my@email.com" to the inputfield "#email"
And I add "1234567" to the inputfield "#password"
And I click on the button "#loginButton"
Then I wait on element "//nav-toolbar//span[contains(text(),'Myself')]" to be visible
And I expect that the attribute "label" from element "#loggedUser" is "Finally, we made it!"
```

And please do not forget to add handling context.behave_drive in your environment.py methods before_all() and after_all() as described in the HOWTO page above.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is read some documentation about, try to take a look on something like taht where you have the most common commands
http://allselenium.info/python-selenium-commands-cheat-sheet-frequently-used/